# Problems getting tk.Radiobutton selected value

Tags: tkinter, radio-button

I am newby to python and I have come to do some script to choose between options using tkinter, but it doesn't seem to work. I have looked many examples and everythin seems to me fine but still does't work. Any help... thx.
   Here is the script that doesn't work:

```
#####################
def entry_value():
    print('Value: %d' % (choice1.get() + choice2.get())
#####################

import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()

tk.Label(master, text="Choice: ").pack()
choice1 = tk.IntVar()
button1 = tk.Radiobutton(master, text="Choice 1", variable=choice1, value=0).pack()
choice2 = tk.IntVar()
button2 = tk.Radiobutton(master, text="Choice 2", variable=choice2, value=1).pack()
tk.Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.quit).pack()
tk.Button(master, text='Show', command=entry_value).pack()

tk.mainloop()
master.destroy()
```

All what I get is:

```
"Value: 0"
"Value: 0"
"Value: 0"
"Value: 0"
```

everytime I press the "Show" button.
Thx!

Answer (score 0):

When you create a set of radiobuttons, they all need to share the same variable for them to be able to work as a set. That is what allows tkinter to provide an exclusive choice.

Change the definition of `button2` to use `choice1` as its variable, and then modify your `entry_value` function to display just that one variable.